# Bank employment Background check denied

Tags: hiring-process, background-check

I need help in regards to my background check that was done by some bank for teller position. I accepted the job got call on  27 July by branch manager saying you are good to go will see you on 1 august 2017.

Today on 31 august I got email from hiring manager stating I didn't satisfy the background check. Therefore offer is withdrawn.

I called the company who does background check they told me your *education check is still pending*. I have been honest about places I worked I have no criminal record and I have proof of my education along with my employment.

Please if anyone can help me here that will be really appreciated

Comment: I believe in the US you have a right to know what information disqualified you in BGC, a copy of the BGC, as well as correspondence with the company that performed the check.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The absolute first thing to remember is to remain calm while dealing with this.  Emotions can make this uncomfortable situation worse for you.  So in any interactions keep calm, ask questions rather than making accusations, and solve the problem rather than burning the bridge.

I would get on the phone (not an email, but a phone call) with the hiring manager. Ask what specifically what criteria were given to your company that disqualify you as an employee. Further, ask if would be able to provide verifiable records, if that would alleviate their concerns.

When you make this call you must be polite, patient and respectful. Of course, you should be these all the time anyway (especially working as a customer service professional!!) but the things your hiring manager says will probably upset and aggravate you and you can't let that happen. You need your hiring manager to fight for your place on the team or you will not be getting this job.

Emphasize the fact that you were hired based on your skills, experience and education and they are all verifiable. The company performing the background check must have made some kind of clerical error. Make sure to use phrases that talk about your future with the company - it's a powerful message that you're committed to getting through this blocker.

That being said, I wouldn't trust someone with their own proof of education. I would want to see it coming from the institution itself (and I'd be willing to pay for a certified copy delivered straight to me.)

Comment: Thanks for thorough reply.Its really helpful i left voicemail to both branch manager and hiring manager.I just don't know if I should go tomorrow morning to my the job ! Confront the branch manager talk with him directly and in terms of hiring manager all I can do is wait for her to get back to me

Comment: If you want to think of it as a "confront" situation. If your goal is to confront him you're gonna have a bad time. If you're going to come in the next day, make it clear that you are committed and willing to clear up whatever the problem is. Your plan should not be to go to work that day but rather to clear up any confusion and set up a plan of action with timelines. Show that you're a professional who can rise above these misunderstandings; who sets goals and works hard to achieve them in spite of whatever circumstances. I know that's the kind of person **I'd** want to hire.

Comment: Okay I ll keep that in mind.Also, something you might wanna interesting here I applied through disability channel for this job.They did this twice now giving offer pulling it back. First one was about around accommodations I needed.Now it's back ground check.I called the company who did background check they told me they did criminal and employment check but education is still pending.However , in the letter I got from HR states I didn't satisfy background check.I will go tomorrow do as you suggested but yeah at this point my depression is coming back :(

Comment: Education is part of your background typically. You have supporting documentation (or you should) yourself.  A copy of your final transcripts should be enough.

Comment: @Ramhound Considering [58% of applicants lie on their resume](http://www.careerbuilder.ca/share/aboutus/pressreleasesdetail.aspx?sd=8%2F7%2F2014&id=pr837&ed=12%2F31%2F2014) I personally wouldn't consider something genuine until I've received it directly from the educational institution.

Comment: @corsika That's why I have sealed copies of my transcripts that were directly sent from the school to me.   Just for this purpose.  I also colored copied my transcripts.  I have never had anyone question my education.  Hard to argue with a scanned copied of a transcript which picked up the security background printed on the paper.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, but if I'm going to be investing tens or hundreds of thousands a year into an employee, plus hundreds of dollars in interview time, I'll front the 20 dollar processing cost and 5 dollar shipping cost to get it from the institution. Maybe that's just me.

Comment: When the first thing someone tells me is not to panic, my first reaction is to try to figure out why something thinks I might panic.  It distracts me from any thing else that is said beyond trying to understand why they think i might panic.  Otherwise great answer

Comment: OP is losing his job offer because of something outside of his control. People tend to panic when their ability to pay their bills is in jeopardy.

Comment: @corsiKa - Yes I have myself, but remind them of what they should do, not what they should avoid.  People focus on the things you say to them , if you say the word panic then panic often becomes the response.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree with you. Being calm is not always what OP wants to do, and I would not want to encourage them to stifle all their emotion simply because some of them go awry. I'm sorry that you have trouble controlling your emotion, and I wish you the best in conquering that. But make no mistake, if OP is not passionate about going after this opportunity it will slip away.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings So while I don't doubt your good intent, I do not condone the message that you edited in. I will ponder (in a while) a way to address your concern, though. It is certainly valid and addressing it improves the answer!

Comment: @corsiKa calm is not dispassionate.  It is not that i have trouble controlling emotion it was that I did not understand why I should.  It feels good to release rage and yell and make those people who are causing you pain feel fear... at least in the short term.  But it is not constructive.  A calm but assertive demeanor on the other hand is one that people want to work with.  It is less immediately satisfying but in the end you know you did everything possible to get the result you wanted.  And in the future interactions with them wont be uncomfortable.

Comment: Calm is literally dispassionate. "(of a person, action, or manner) *not showing* or feeling nervousness, anger, or other *emotions*" - and there are certainly ways to be passionate that are not calm yet are also not raging. I've said my peace - I disagree with your wording but haven't the time to correct it at the moment. fin.

Comment: Hi there I heard back from the bank I applied for teller job.It seems that only one of my employers from past didn't give very nice review about me when they did the background check.Based only one bad review bank has decided to withdraw the offer.I called the employer who provide not full context of story of actuall happened.After speaking to them it turns out managers and supervisor I had all of them no longer works there all there is left is there notes about me which I personally feel misrepresentations of me as they didn't provide me accommodation in regards to my mental health.

Comment: Therefore I was let go.Also,I do not recall lot of stuff they said to the bank in back ground ever happenedTherefore,I ended up sending email to HR from the bank stating it's misrepresentation what you have been given by my employer.Just waiting now hoping they will listen to my plea :(